# Counter clock wise vs clock wise angle difference

Tags: complex-numbers

So today I got my maths exam back. And my teacher didnt gave me mark on this one example.
Write this $z=-3$ in polar coordinates and my answer was: $r=3$ and angle=$-180^\circ$. My teacher said that the angle is wrong because we find angle in counter clock wise not in clock wise. But still $-180^\circ$ lands on same results as $180^\circ$ does. Are there any rules which prohibit me to measure angles in clock wise?

Comment: The convention is typically to write $z = |z| \mathrm{e}^{i \operatorname{Arg}(z)}$, where $\operatorname{Arg}$ is the principle argument.  Since this is a number in $(-\pi, \pi]$, it is likely "more correct" (depending on context) to write $\pi$ (or $180^\circ$, don't forget the units!).

Answer (score 1):

If your teacher specified that the [principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) of a complex number lies within $(-180,180]$ or $[0,360)$, then he is right. Else you could choose your own interval.

Comment: Well there were no interval given. He just here is the complex number and write it in polar coordinates. Thats it. Unlucky me man. Only if I got this right then I would have got a 3, but nah. He gave me five thus I failed thr exam. :(. Well next time need to work harder

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the definition.

I like to define the argument in $[0,2\pi).$

Maybe your teacher gave the similar definition?

Comment: He didnt. He just wrote here is the complex number and write it in polar coordinates. Thats it. Nothing more nothing less

Comment: If so you are right, I think.

Comment: I tried my best at convincing him, but he didnt change his opinion. I even told him what if I can bring him the proofs, but my man just got angry at me.

Answer (score 0):

No, your answer isn't technically wrong, but I guess that in class, you would have defined the angle to be in the range $-180^\circ<\theta\le180^\circ$ or $0^\circ\le\theta<360^\circ$, in which case your angle is not correct.